# Updating the same field twice in the same transaction

Tags: automation, duplicate-management

Does anyone have any suggestions on ways to set a boolean field to TRUE then set the same field to FALSE within the same transaction?

I'm attempting to Bypass Duplicate Rules using a checkbox at the start of automation which sets to TRUE and setting that same checkbox to FALSE at the end of the PB/WF/Flow Transaction.

Everything I've come across so far, does this update in a new transaction e.g, Scheduled Paths. I'm also attempting to avoid a Before Trigger then updating the field again using Workflow Rules... If possible, I'm attempting to stick with declarative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine (which you no doubt have) the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

A declarative solution would use

- A Before Save Flow (Step 3) to set the checkbox such that Duplicate Rules were skipped (Step 6)
- A Workflow Rule that used a field update to toggle the checkbox (Step 11); duplicate rules are not rerun (Step 11)

Of course, one might ask why you would allow a duplicate record to get into the system in the first place as subsequent DML to this or other records with the same matching rule keys could trigger the duplicate rule

Record-triggered flows with scheduled paths run in a new transaction and just start the save procedure all over again